# WCF Soap Header with PasswordText

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-8.1

We are working on a Windows 8 Store application which is accessing a WCF Service. For Security the SVC has a Credentials to be provided to access every method available out there. The Password type has been set as PasswordText. When i try to access the WCF i am getting an error as **"An error occurred when verifying security for the message.”**  My Client side code is as follows:

```
CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding();
binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
binding.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement( MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressing10, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));
binding.Elements.Add(new HttpTransportBindingElement());
binding.Name = "ClearUsernameBinding_IUserDetailsService";

EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://MyURL"));
ServiceReference1.UserDetailsServiceClient proxy = new ServiceReference1.UserDetailsServiceClient(binding, endpoint);

proxy.Endpoint.Contract.Name = "IScheduledVisitsService";
proxy.Endpoint.Contract.ConfigurationName = "ClearUsernameBinding_IScheduledVisitsService";
proxy.Endpoint.Address = endpoint;
proxy.Endpoint.Binding = binding;
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = Loginmodel.UserName;
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = Loginmodel.Password;
UserDTO result =  await proxy.GetUserByUsernameAsync(Loginmodel.UserName);
```

It seems the password has to be set a PasswordText, Any idea how to get this resolved

Comment: What type of security is being used?

Comment: We have used only the Header credentials and nothing else. The credentials provided out here is creating this issue. The Service requires the password type as PasswordText

Comment: Do you have access to the servers error logs/Event Viewer? Because that generic **"An error occurred when verifying security for the message.”** message could mean many things. Most commonly for us we have clients submitting and the SOAP created/expires datetimes are too  far out of whack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did to get it to work:

```
            CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding();

            binding.Name = "ClearUsernameBinding_IUserDetailsService";

            binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
            binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
            binding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
            binding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            binding.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));
            binding.Elements.Add(TransportSecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement());
            binding.Elements.Add(new HttpsTransportBindingElement());


            EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://MYURL"));
            ServiceReference1.UserDetailsServiceClient proxy = new ServiceReference1.UserDetailsServiceClient(binding, endpoint);

            proxy.Endpoint.Contract.Name = "IScheduledVisitsService";
            proxy.Endpoint.Contract.ConfigurationName = "ClearUsernameBinding_IScheduledVisitsService";
            proxy.Endpoint.Address = endpoint;
            proxy.Endpoint.Binding = binding;
            proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = Loginmodel.UserName;
            proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = Loginmodel.Password;
            UserDTO result = await proxy.GetUserByUsernameAsync(Loginmodel.UserName);
```

Which is the equivalent of the following if done in config

```
    <binding name="myBinding">
      <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default" authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"
        requireDerivedKeys="true"
        includeTimestamp="true"
        messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
      </security>
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
    </binding>`
```

But like SuMMeR said, this will only work with HTTPS. If you want to allow for insecure, you can add the `allowInsecureTransport="true"` to the `<security>` element in the config file. If you want to do it in code, I think you could just try something like:

```
TransportSecurityBindingElement mySecElement = new TransportSecurityBindingElement {  AllowInsecureTransport = true };
binding.Elements.Add(mySecElement);
```

Comment: Thanks Lammmy.

I have complied this code and i am getting this following error as i am not using the HTTPS and i am using http.

As WCF is running internally we aren't using HTTPS

Comment: LaMMMY, I tried adding this ALlowInsecureTransport code snippet in my application and it shows that this Property(AllowInsecureTransport) is not available. I am using Windows 8.1 app and .NET Framework 4.5. 

Any Idea to Resolve this

Comment: I too am using .Net 4.5, but a winforms app. Did you do it like I did above? That's the only way I could get it to work, it would not allow for `binding.Elements.Add(new HttpsTransportBindingElement { AllowInsecureTransport = True});` in the same manner as you posted. The HttpsTransportBindingElement had to be created, then added to the binding.Elements after creation (like I posted).

Comment: I am using this in windows store styled applicaton here.

Answer (score 0):

By default it is not allowed to send client credentials in an unsecure way in WCF. So look at the following senarious how to protect your service:

[Transport Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733775%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Message Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731058%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also there is a workarownd that allows to send client credentials unencrypted over HTTP:
[SecurityBindingElement.AllowInsecureTransport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.securitybindingelement.allowinsecuretransport%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). But you shouldn't use it in production because it opens a serious security flaw.